# Histograma R. Trocando os valores dos eixos!

Tags: r, histograma

Tenho uma variável com o seguinte valor:

```
> pontos
        c         d         b         a 
0.6666667 1.0000000 0.3333333 0.6666667
```

hist(pontos, main="Pontos ", xlab="p", ylab= "f")

o resultado é:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Os meu valores do eixo X ficarão sempre entre 0 e 1. Já os valores dos eixos y podem alterar de 0 até 100000000. Gostaria de inverter! Ou seja, os valores entre 0 e 1 ficarem no eixo Y e os valores de frequência, que é a quantidade que cada valor aparece, ficar no eixo X.

Vi um parametro do tipo, horizontal = TRUE. Não é isso que eu quero, é simplesmente trocar os valores dos eixos, valores que estão no eixo X aparecer no Y e vice-versa. Sei que com isso a estrutura do histograma irá mudar, mas não importa, porque o eixo Y ficará imenso quando os valores aumentar, e acho mais interessante esses valores ficarem no eixo X.

É quase um barplot! A única coisa que não quero, é que quando houver repetição de valor, como no exemplo abaixo, não apareça 2 barras, mas sim somente uma, e no eixo X informando que há 2 barras com valor informado no eixo Y.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Esse gráfico parece ser indefinido. E quando dois pontos aparecerem a mesma quantidade de vezes? Como vai ficar a barra?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

O truque aqui é perceber que é possível fazer um histograma tradicional e salvar as informações referentes à sua construção em um objeto. Por exemplo,

```
pontos <- c(0.6666667, 1.0000000, 0.3333333, 0.6666667)
histograma <- hist(pontos)
str(histograma)
List of 6
 $ breaks  : num [1:5] 0.2 0.4 0.6 0.8 1
 $ counts  : int [1:4] 1 0 2 1
 $ density : num [1:4] 1.25 0 2.5 1.25
 $ mids    : num [1:4] 0.3 0.5 0.7 0.9
 $ xname   : chr "pontos"
 $ equidist: logi TRUE
 - attr(*, "class")= chr "histogram"
```

Assim, basta utilizar algumas das informações presentes no objeto `histograma` para criar um novo gráfico de frequências, rotacionado em 90 graus:

```
plot(NULL, type = "n", xlim = c(0, max(histograma$counts)),
ylim = c(range(histograma$breaks)), xlab="Frequência", ylab="Pontos")

rect(0, histograma$breaks[1:(length(histograma$breaks) - 1)], 
histograma$counts, histograma$breaks[2:length(histograma$breaks)])
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

É possível criar uma função baseada neste código acima para facilitar o teu trabalho toda vez que um histograma parecido precisar ser criado.

Comment: Marcus, eu nao quero que o histograma fique deitado. Quero q ele fique na vertical! Entendeu?

Comment: @Filipe, tente fazer na mão esse exemplo que você deu. A dimensão das barras perderá totalmente o sentido se você trocar o label dos eixos. Tem certeza de que é isso que você quer?